# Use compiled system MySql gem in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

With Rails 2.8 I am using a system gem compiled on a Solaris server, used as production. Rails 3 uses bundler and when I deploy with Capistrano and execute bundle install, bundler is not capable to install that gem. MySql gem must be compiled from source as I documented here: http://riccardotacconi.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-install-mysqlruby-on-solaris.html. Is there a way to tell to bundler/Rails3 to use the system MySql gem? This problem is blocking my deployment problem and crashing the applicaiton.

Answer (score 1):

You can define where you gem is whith :path

```
gem 'mysql', :path => '/path_to_mysql_in_system'
```

Comment: ** [out :: servername] Could not find gem 'mysql (>= 0, runtime)' in source at /usr/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1.
 ** [out :: servername] Source does not contain any versions of 'mysql (>= 0, runtime)'